# Is there a faster way to generate video from pixel arrays using python and ffmpeg?

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg

I've found a few sources which use python and ffmpeg to generate video from pixel arrays by passing the `-f rawvideo` flag [1](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/) [2](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9f7e624deede078a1c489155bcbd9c9dfd408a57/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L633-L635). However, this is very slow for high-definition video since each individual pixel must be piped into ffmpeg.

In fact this is provably wasteful, as I've found that 2.5Gb of pixel arrays generates about 80Kb of video. I've also chanced upon some examples where javascript can render high quality animations in near-real time [1](http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/), which makes me even more suspicious that I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently, perhaps by piping the differences between pixel arrays into ffmpeg rather than the pixels themselves?

(edit) [This](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/1da185953c2a0109fe5f3b789e43d33b4d31a0bf/manimlib/scene/scene_file_writer.py#L213-L223) is the line I'm using. Most executions take the `else` path that follows.

Answer (score 0):

Raw, uncompressed video requires a lot of memory, that is why it should be compressed as early as possible.  But the earliest time in your case is when it has reached ffmpeg - you don't want to develop a video encoder.  Piping in essence is the handover of memory buffers between processes, so there is not be much overhead if this is done right (eg. handing over complete frames instead of small buffers).

Rendering an animation is a different task than video compression, so there is no point in comparison.

What video compression parameters do you use?  Show us the complete ffmpeg command line.